# Winmerge: Filter for file types and include subfolders

Tags: regex, filter, winmerge

I have created a filter in winmerge so that it only compares the spesific file types. The filter look as follows:

```
def: exclude
f: \.xml$
f: \.csv$
f: \.rteparams$
f: \.rteswb$
f: \.rteudp$
f: \.rte$
f: \.cfg$
```

This works fine, but the compare does not check within subfolder, even though I have selected "include subfolders".

If I add a line in the filter:

```
d: \\CONFIGURATION$
```

Then it will check this folder as well. However I have too many folders so I cannot add them all. If I add this line:

```
d: \\*$
```

It will then go through all subfolders, but will check all file types and not only the ones I have specified.

Anyone who can help? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `f: \\*\.xml$` ?

Comment: I tried now, but same result

Answer (score 1):

Frustratingly, the only way I could do this with WinMerge was use an include (def:include) filter and build a big file extension list with PowerShell.  Remember WinMerge filter of "include" means "Inclusive (loose) filter lets through all items not matching rules".  Cludge but works.

PowerShell:

```
gci C:\PathTo\YourFolder\* -exclude *.bat, *.pl -recurse | select Extension | % { $ext = $_.Extension; if (${ext}){ echo "f: \${ext}$" } } | sort -uniq
```

You would add argument values in the '-exclude ' argument for all the extensions that you want WinMerge to compare.

Downside is when you scan a new folder or coworkers add new files with extensions such as '.backup5', you have to cringe and bear looking at the junk, or rebuild or edit your filter.